Trying to remember a short involving an impenetrable barrier inside a tower
The story involved a tower on earth which might have been called the "pen" or "umbra" (penumbra?), and there was some sort of anomaly inside it. Humanity was trying to penetrate a forcefield in the anomaly without success.
Someone eventually figured out that a kind of sentience was purposefully blocking them from the other side, and that if they used randomly-timed strikes on the barrier they could get through.
Read before ~2008. Possibly part of an anthology.

Could it be "The Pen and the Dark" (1966), one of Colin Kapp's "Unorthodox Engineer" stories?
In the story, the Engineers attempt to solve the mystery of a huge alien artefact on the surface of the planet Ithica, in the form of a gigantic black cylinder kilometres high known as "the Dark" which appears to absorb all energy, and surrounding it is a penumbra dubbed "the Pen", a zone where energy is progressively damped as one approaches the Dark.
The Engineers investigate the Dark by driving a large diameter pipe into it, section by section using explosives, and at the end of the story one of them crawls through the pipe and causes the whole thing to collapse.

I've just quickly re-read "The Pen and the Dark" and I agree this is a match
